# How could netty select() take so much time?

Tags: java, netty, nio

According to the sampler of visualvm:

[image]

I'm new to Netty, but when I profiling one Java application, it seems that `select()` take 85% of `self time`. But the `self time(CPU)` is just a very very small part. So if I understand the `self time` and `self time(CPU)` correctly, it means the `select()` just waiting all the time. Does it normal for server side code? Will such many waits cost much CPU usage? My server has 12 cores CPU with 2.4 GHz. This java application has costed almost 200% in `top` (a taskmgr like tool in linux).

Comment: It spends most of its time blocked waiting for an event. This is normal.

Comment: @EJP Dose this waiting cost cpu usage ?

Comment: It says, 386ms, so not very much.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time spent in `select()` is your application's *down time*. The application appears to be multithreaded, with high degree of parallelization, and very high CPU usage, once it gets the data. The time in `select()`, however, represents the time when your application does *not* have the data, so it is blocked while it is waiting for the network operation to complete.

This matches your observation of about 200% CPU usage using `top`. On a 12-core system, 200% corresponds to 2/12, or about 16% of the total available CPU time. Assuming that nothing else is running on your system, the downtime is (100-16), or about 84% - i.e. roughly the time spent in `select()`, as shown by `visualvm`.